# The omission of definite articles for the title of a book

Tags: grammaire, articles, noms-propres

I was just wondering if anyone knew why the definite article is omitted here: L'auteur de Rouge et Noir.

Do you know the grammatical rule behind it? I have done a fair bit of reading and the only reason I could find is due to the use of de+noun, which makes it function similar to an adjective or attribute, such as "une maison de campagne."

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Stendhal's book title is ***Le Rouge et le Noir***.

We might say one of the following:

- ***L'auteur de Le Rouge et Le Noir*** but ***de le*** doesn't sound good in French. It is better with a pause and guillemets: ***L'auteur de « Le Rouge et Le Noir »***.
- ***L'auteur du « Rouge et le Noir »***, still slightly odd but common.
- ***L'auteur du Rouge et du Noir***, is correct grammar but the title is kind of "disrespected".
- ***L'auteur de Rouge et Noir***, the title is abbreviated, no more issues with ***de le*** although some (many?) would argue the title is even more "disrespected".

  André Breton nevertheless used it:

  > Peu de romans sont mieux composés que « Rouge et Noir » [...].

  Another occurrence:

  > *Conjectures sur l’origine scottienne du titre de « Rouge et Noir ».* Henri-François Imbert, Revue de Littérature Comparée, N°45, 1971.

If you reject all of the above suggestions, you can still say:

- ***L'auteur de l'œuvre Le rouge et le Noir*** (or *du livre*, *de l'ouvrage*, *du roman* etc.)

Comment: Les deux premières semblent acceptables. Il me semble avoir plutôt entendu la seconde. Parfois les gens optent pour la périphrase "l'auteur du livre ...." pour éviter le problème.

Comment: Je ne dirais pas "l'auteur de Rouge et Noir" - d'abord, ce n'est pas le titre officiel. Ensuite, il faut faire preuve d'un peu plus de respect envers l'auteur et l'oeuvre. Enfin, ça sonne comme une erreur d'un non-francophone qui ne fait aucun effort pour utiliser le titre correct. Même en anglais, je vois _The red and the black" as the translation. Et puis, _rouge_ et _noir_ sont utilisés comme noms ici, pas comme adjectifs.